# Change UISegmentedControl titles programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

How can i change UISegmentedControl titles programmatically? Could you please help me?

```
@synthesize filterControl; //UISegmentedControl

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    filterControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ALL",@"PROFIT",@"LOSS", nil]]; //not working

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have u added filterControl as subview to its superview?

Comment: I have added manually, and its working fine. Only i need to change these titles programatically. Could u please help me?

Comment: use this API

- (void)insertSegmentWithTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated;

Comment: When use this code, its inserting a new one, how can i remove the existing segments?

Comment: Thank you Allamaprabhu, I have fixed like this: [filterControl removeAllSegments]; [filterControl insertSegmentWithTitle: @"1" atIndex: 0 animated: NO]; [filterControl insertSegmentWithTitle: @"2" atIndex: 0 animated: NO];

Answer (score 6):

Just use

```
-setTitle:(NSString*)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `sectionTitles` directly.

What is often missed out is calling `setNeedsDisplay()`.

The code in Swift:

```
segmentedControl.sectionTitles = ["All", "Profit", "Loss"]
segmentedControl.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: Not applicable in Swift 5. There is no such function like .sectionTitles

Answer (score 1):

```
 [filterControl setTitle:@"All" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
 [filterControl setTitle:@"PROFIT" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
 [filterControl  setTitle:@"LOSS" forSegmentAtIndex:2];
```

try this. hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Updated :

***Use below simple code to set UISegmentControl title programatically;***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

     [self.segmentControl setTitle:@"Love It" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
     [self.segmentControl setTitle:@"Hate It" forSegmentAtIndex:1];        
     [self.segmentControl setTitle:@"Ehh" forSegmentAtIndex:2];
}
```

*// Note: here  self.segmentControl = filterControl*

Answer (score 0):

***Swift5***

To change title font and size for HmSegment control you have to make use of titleTextAttributes property.

```
segmentedControl.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-Medium", size: 16.0) as Any]
segmentedControl.setNeedsDisplay()
```